# Problem when uploading an image to tumblr using php/curl

Tags: php, api, file-upload, curl, tumblr

I've been trying to create a simple php file that will upload a single image to tumblr. An example is listed [here](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api#api_write), but it just won't work with images. Here is the code:

```
<?php
// Authorization info
$tumblr_email    = 'lol@something.com';
$tumblr_password = 'secret';

// Data for new record
$post_type  = 'photo';

//////////////////////THIS DOESN'T WORK/////////////////////////////////
//$filename = "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/1.jpeg";
//$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
//$post_data = fread($handle, filesize($filename));

//////////////////////NEITHER DOES THIS/////////////////////////////////
//$post_data = "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/1.jpg";

///////////////////////////////NOR THIS/////////////////////////////////
//$filename = "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/1.jpeg";
//$post_data = fopen($filename, "r");


// Prepare POST request
$request_data = http_build_query(
    array(
        'email'     => $tumblr_email,
        'password'  => $tumblr_password,
        'type'      => $post_type,
        'data'      => $post_data,
        'generator' => 'testing tumblr API example'
    )
);

// Send the POST request (with cURL)
$c = curl_init('http://www.tumblr.com/api/write');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request_data);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($c);
$status = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($c);

// Check for success
if ($status == 201) {
    echo "Success! The new post ID is $result.\n";
} else if ($status == 403) {
    echo 'Bad email or password';
} else {
    echo "Error: $result\n";
}

?>
```

I am not that familiar with php/curl, so I have no idea what am I doing wrong. This is also written on tumblr.com:

> File uploads can be done in a data parameter where specified above. You may use either of the common encoding methods:
>
> 1) multipart/form-data method, like a file upload box in a web form. Maximum size:
>
> ...10 MB for photos...
>
> This is recommended since there's much less overhead.
>
> 2) Normal POST method, in which the file's entire binary contents are URL-encoded like any other POST variable. Maximum size:
>
> ...5 MB for photos...

Thanks.

Comment: Define "Won't work". What happens? Also, *do* your images exceed the 5/10 MB limit?

Comment: Tumblr sends this message: "Error uploading photo."

Comment: Oh, and a sample image is way smaller then 5MB. But the funny thing is, the script works when I supply it with the same image located on a remote server (http://...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Authorization info
$tumblr_email    = 'lol@something.com';
$tumblr_password = 'secret';

// Data for new record
$post_type  = 'photo';

$post_data = "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/1.jpg";

$request_data = array(
        'email'     => $tumblr_email,
        'password'  => $tumblr_password,
        'type'      => $post_type,
        'data'      => '@'.$post_data,
        'generator' => 'testing tumblr API example'
);

// Send the POST request (with cURL)
$c = curl_init('http://www.tumblr.com/api/write');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request_data);
```

You need to pass an array to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, and prepend the absolute path to the file with an @. This will make cURL post the data as multipart/form-data.